# Extract URL's from a Cell of Text in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, excel-formula, formula

I have an Excel document with a column that contains cells of text (small paragraphs usually). I'd like to find a way (preferably a formula) to extract any url's those cells by row and add them to another column.

I've been messing around with MID and FIND quite a bit and can very easily get to the begginning of those URLs by searching for "http", but I can't figure out how to then find the length of the url so I can grab it.

Really looking forward to any help anyone could offer. It's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take into account the URL happening at the end of a string you'll need to add some error handling.

This should work for both mid string and end of string:

```
=MID(C11,FIND("http",C11),IFERROR(FIND(" ",C11,FIND("http",C11))-1,LEN(C11))-FIND("http",C11)+1)
```

Comment: Just added one more little tweak, wrapping the whole thing in an IFERROR in the case where the text didn't contain any instances of "http".

Comment: Good call @ChrisVasquez!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I've got it working. Check it out:

```
=MID(C11,FIND("http",C11),(FIND(" ",C11,FIND("http",C11))-FIND("http",C11))-4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've identified the start position of the URL look for the first space after that, should be the end of the URL.

Comment: space or end of string

Comment: That's a great idea. Assuming I've used SEARCH or FIND to find out that the string starts at char 24, what's the best way to get the string length from there?

Comment: Ok, I think I've got something working. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score -1):

Your most likely option is to make sure you can rely on the URLs being formed the same way.  Like, always start with "http" and always end with "/" or a ".com".  Then you can do formulas to find the index start, index end, and grab the MID for everything in between.

It should look like this:

```
=FIND("http",D3)
```

returns the location of the first part.

```
=FIND(".com",D3)
```

returns the location of the end

```
=MID(D3,D9,D10-D9+4)
```

Returns the string provided by the start to the end+4 (to allow for those 4 characters)

Comment: Assuming an URL ends with `.com` is just plain wrong. It might as well be the beginning of a domain name (ex: `somesubdomain.computer.net`). But more importantly because there are a lot of [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) other than `.com`

Comment: That's why I said "assuming".  It could just as easily end with "HTML" or "PHP".  The proof of concept is correct nonetheless.

Comment: Well no. Let's assume the domain ends with `.com`. What about the rest of the url? like `/imghp?hl=en` in `http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en`